# What is happening in the background when we pause a game? And how the game resume and starts?

Tags: java, android

What is happening in the background when we pause a game? And how does the game resume and restart?

I want to know the step by step scenario. I faced this question in an interview and I could not answer it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are commands such as `onResume()` , `onPause()`, `onRestart()` that are used to implement what you want to know. However, follow this link for better and clear picture: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the application lifecycle. Take a look at the [videos](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html) in the developer docs. Click on the tab "About the Platform" and watch the first three videos. The video "Androidology – Part 2 of 3 – Application Lifecycle" answers your question very clearly.